# String comparsion in win32 C++

Tags: c++, string, winapi

I want to write a simple programm that if SbieCtrl.exe process is running in my machine, My program report it in output. But my code doesn't work. I put my code in the following :

My Class Code :

```
    bool processTools(string processName) {

    HANDLE hProcessSnap;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if (hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        procRunning = false;
    }
    else {
        pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
        if (Process32First(hProcessSnap, &pe32)) { 
            if (pe32.szExeFile == processName) {
                procRunning = true;
            }
            else {
                while (Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32)) {
                    compare = pe32.szExeFile;
                    if (compare == processName) {
                        procRunning = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
        }
    }

    return procRunning;
}
```

My Object Code:

```
class Sandboxie : Base {
public:
    int SandboxieProcess() {
        if (processTools("SbieCtrl.exe")) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
};
```

Why this code doesn't work. I has several error like comparsion in "if (pe32.szExeFile == processName)" section.

Comment: What is the type for `compare`?  Is it a function pointer?  An std::string?  A C-Style string?  A Windows String?

Comment: To add to what Thomas is asking, what type is pe32.szExeFile? Also, post the actual compiler error.

Comment: Not all string types have `operator==()` overloaded, especially C-Style strings.

Comment: What is `string`? Is it `std::string`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Type of compare is string. and type of processName is string too.

Comment: @MrEricSir Error : no operator "==" matches to these operandes. for if (pe32.szExeFile == processName) section.

Comment: @immibis yes. it is std:String

Comment: Why don't you do some debugging. That would be so much easier than using SO as a proxy debugger. All you need to do is inspect your program's state. The inability to debug is by far the most glaring weakness of beginners. Make it your mission to learn how to debug.

Comment: @the_milad What type is pe32.szExeFile?

Comment: I looked it up, pe32.szExeFile is a WCHAR[260], so if you change your parameter to a wstring, it should compile fine.

Answer (score -2):

I solved it. I go to properties section of the project in Visual studio and changed the parameter of Charachter Set to Multi-byte charachter set and now everything works fine.

Comment: Using multibyte characters is the wrong fix. You really need to be using Unicode. Unicode is the native type for all the Windows NT APIs and multibyte has to do a lot of conversion. Also there are continuing rumors that Microsoft will remove multibyte support from some future version of Visual Studio although old apps will of course keep working. Although I have to check, I believe Microsoft's newest framework for Universal apps *requires* Unicode and not MBCS.

Comment: So what should i do dear to fix this problem? @ZanLynx

Comment: I think someone else had the right answer to use `std::wstring` which holds UTF-16 Unicode points on Windows. The `szExeFile` is declared as `TCHAR     szExeFile[MAX_PATH]` so `TCHAR` will be defined as `wchar` if you put the compiler setting back to Unicode instead of MBCS.

Comment: Oh and `wchar` string constants use a capital `L` in front like this: `L"wide string with Unicode like Japanese: 新商品情報"`